# ng-repeat does not render uib-accordion-group

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have object. It is grouped by emails. Key of every property is first letter of emails in this group. The problem is, that if key is '$', group is not rendered on view.

```
$scope.groups = {
 $: [
  {
    attributes: {email: '$mail@mail.com'}
  },
  {
    attributes: {email: '$mail2@mail.com'}
  }
 ],
 C: [
  {
    attributes: {email: 'cmail@mail.com'}
  },
  { 
    attributes: {email: 'cmail2@mail.com'}
  }
 ]
};
```

According to requirements, I cannot deprecate such emails. So I need it to be on the page. $sce didn't help. 
Please, see the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCvZLfksQZ79HszUDcMN?p=preview).

Can anyone help me to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you injected ngSanitize as dependency?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, it didn't help

Comment: try using ng-safe-html. It may works.

Comment: What is ng-safe-html? I've tried to use ngSanitize. It didn't work for me

Comment: from documentation: ngRepeat will silently ignore object keys starting with $, because it's a prefix used by Angular for public ($) and private ($$) properties.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a special character for AngularJS. I suggest you to rename the key `$` by something similar (`dollar` for example), then it will show fine:

```
$scope.groups = {
    ...
    dollar: [ // instead of $
       {
         attributes: {email: '$mail@mail.com'}
       },
       {
         attributes: {email: '$mail2@mail.com'}
       }
    ],
    ...
}
```

If you want to show a "$" in your page, you can use ng-if on your span:

```
    <span ng-if="key !='dollar'">{{key}}</span>
    <span ng-if="key == 'dollar'">$</span>
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TKwMcNkgdH0sOxEGphmQ?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Object is not hardcoded. It's generated, and is fully editable. So it's averhead to check symbol every operation.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... The problem is that you have many rows in your object that start with a `$`?

Comment: No, the problem is, that if I'll add email starting with '$', I need to show group '$', and email in it. But it doesn't render such groups. Please, see the plunker

Comment: whenever the object is generated in UI, just check for $ and do what Mistalis has suggested, or you can write your own ng-repeat kind of directive, or change the code for ng-repeat to suit your needs.